# classify cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, document-classification

I want to do text categorization on a dataset of news. I have a lot of features like `subject`, `keyword`, `summary`, etc... all of these features are stored in one cell array of structs, each struct looking like this:

```
       label: 'misc.forsale'
        subj: ' Motorcycle wanted.'
     keyword: [1x190 char]
   reference: []
organization: ' Worcester Polytechnic Institute'
        from: ' kedz@bigwpi.WPI.EDU (John Kedziora)'
     summary: []
       lines: ' 11'
       vocab: [4x2 double]
```

I want to classify them with `class = classify(test, train, target, 'diaglinear');`
but these functions only receive arrays as input, and do not accept cells or structs.

I can't convert this cell array to *one* multidimensional array because the amount of features varies (for example, one subject has two words and other has three words).

What can I do?

Comment: don't you have to first extract some features for each document, something like the [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf*idf)

Comment: Yes, I do it. but In this way that you mentioned, I didn't use subjects, keywords separately. I think in this way I have lost some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some feature extraction first. For example, tokenize the strings, then use TF-IDF.

You can include the key with the tokens. This is a common practise in information retrieval. See the Xapian manual for an example.

Usually, you will do some stemming, e.g. `Examples -> exampl`. Now, just add a prefix to make the words distinct depending on their occurrence. E.g. `Sexampl` when the subject contained `example` and `Kexampl` when it was a keyword.

Then you have a "bag of words" representation that is used everywhere. They even do this for mining images, it's called "visual words" then. These aren't english-language words either.